# Make not-master-branch to pull from master branch

Tags: git

When I `git pull` from a branch that is not master, I get following response.

> You asked me to pull without telling me which branch you want to merge
>   with, and 'branch.not_master.merge'  in your configuration file does
>   not tell me, either. Please specify which branch you want to use on
>   the command line and try again (e.g. 'git pull 
>   ').

What I want to configure is to let this branch to accept pull from the master, as well as its remote branch.

Is it possible to do that?

for instance

```
//on a branch A that is not master.
git pull master //pull from remote HEAD and merge without warning
git pull        //pull from A and merge
```

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388278/git-pull-you-asked-me-to-pull-without-telling-me-which-branch-you-want-to-merge
it give a good method solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

Like the message says, setup `branch.not_master.merge` to `refs/heads/not_master` so that when you do `git pull` it will pull from the same branch on the remote ( also make sure `branch.not_master.remote` is set to the remote, say, `origin` )

For pulling in other branch, you have to write it as `git pull origin master`, as you cannot omit the remote in this case.

Comment: I accidently did. `git config branch.not_master.merge to refs/heads/master` What does that mean? It seems that I cannot commit from not_master branch because it is [rejected] and (non-fast-forward).... I think I made a big mistake

Answer (score 0):

git pull should be used when pulling from a remote repository.  you need to specify the remote resource, for example:

git pull origin master

git merge can take just the local branch name, and doesn't need the remote resource:

git merge master