# Git pull doesn't know which branch to merge with

Tags: git, pull

I committed and pushed.

Someone else then changed something in my branch, committed and pushed.
I tried to pull, as I wanted to get these changes.

Result:

```
From servername
3de3ee5..4db9ed8  Andrea     -> origin/Andrea
You asked me to pull without telling me which branch you
want to merge with, and 'branch.Andrea.merge' in
your configuration file does not tell me, either. Please
specify which branch you want to use on the command line and
try again (e.g. 'git pull <repository> <refspec>').
See git-pull(1) for details.
```

The thing is I do not understand this explanation.
My branch name is definitely `Andrea`, however, `git pull andrea` does not work either.
How can I pull?

Comment: git pull origin Andrea

Comment: I'm guessing that when pushing you didn't really set the pushed branch to be the "upstream" of your local one. Try `git branch -u origin/Andrea Andrea`, then pull again. That said it's only a guess, you should see if you can provide us with steps to reproduce the error you mention.

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388278/you-asked-me-to-pull-without-telling-me-which-branch-you-want-to-merge-with ? it looks similar.

Comment: Thank you, question answered.

Comment: @newnewbie Don't forget to mark your Question as answered or close it

Answer (score 0):

This will pull from the branch origin/Andrea.
Very useful when you change your branch to pull from ofter.
In case you pull from the same branch often, you might want to set it in the settings as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388278/you-asked-me-to-pull-without-telling-me-which-branch-you-want-to-merge-with)

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.